# Fourier transform of sampled data

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have got some impulse response data that I would like to transform via `Fourier` to get the amplitude-frequency characteristics of the performing loudspeaker. The final goal is to show (e.g. via `ListDensityPlot`) how the calculated amplitude-frequency characteristics is dependant on the window I choose to transform (truncation of low frequencies). The issue I have is to get `Fourier` to behave like desired - I am unable to reproduce the frequency response that I got out of another 3rd part software. The issue:

There is no `SampleRate` option for `Fourier` (and I got a sampling frequency of 48kHz)

The following example illustrates the issues:

```
data = Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 100}];

ListPlot[
Take[10*Log10[(Abs@Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}])^2], 
Floor@(Length[Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]]/2)], 
Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: fourier]

```
Periodogram[data, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, SampleRate -> 1, 
PlotRange -> Full, ScalingFunctions -> "dB"]
```

[image: periodogram]

Comment: You are not using the same processing methods. Try `ScalingFunctions -> "Absolute"`, and compare against a `ListPlot` of the `Fourier` transform, not `ListLogPlot`. However, as posted, the two plots are identical except for their scale.

Comment: Figured that as well just this instant. The only issue is still to incorporate the sampling frequency when using `Fourier`. I will change the question accordingly.

Comment: `ListLogPlot` applies `Log10` to the data and makes y-axis ticks in logarithmic style. But `dB` aren't just `Log10` it's `10*Log10`. And also `SampleRate` needs to be changed to number of data points, 100 in your case.

Comment: The issue is that my actual data has a sample frequency of 48000Hz and that I can't find any option to tell `Fourier` that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
samplerate = 48000;
time = Length[data]/samplerate;
nyq = Floor[Length[data]/2]; 
ListPlot[
 Take[10*Log10[(Abs@Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}])^2], nyq], 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full, 
 DataRange -> {0, (nyq - 1)/time}]
```

[image]

Compare with periodigram with given sample rate of 48 kHz:

```
Periodogram[data, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, SampleRate -> 48000, 
 PlotRange -> Full, ScalingFunctions -> "dB"]
```

[image]